# PHP Laravel cURL API Cookie not been used

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5, restful-authentication

I'm using an HTTP RESTFUL API to get json files. I'm trying to get apiCredentials using cURL php, see the code below.

```
    <?php  
        $url = 'http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v2.1/Login/Autenticar?token='.$token;
        $curl = curl_init($url);


        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");

        $cookiesFile = 'cookies.txt';
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiesFile);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiesFile); 

        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        echo $result;

    ?>
```

I'm getting **True** as result. But can't use other API methods because i'm receiving **{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}** when i try to use it.

I'm genarating a cookie.txt file in my public folder, but is not been used  for some reason.

I think the problem is that i'm not able to use the cookie created by API but i'm not sure if i'm using cURL as i should.

Don't know if it matters, but i'm also using laravel framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Should token be `$token` instead?

[image]

Edit: Okay, as this was just a typo, I checked if I get data from my server. I do not get any content on this URI (and I don't know the service tho). If you remove the params and put them into post fields, you get a response.

```
$url = 'http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v2.1/Login/Autenticar';
        $post = ["token" => "asd"];

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        echo $result;
```

And then you get: `{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v2.1/Login/Autenticar'."}`

Either way, the server returns not an error but 0x200, to check with `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch))`. So I think it depends on whatever you send as a token, be it in payload or URI

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually this is a typo i made when i was getting the code to stackoverflow, i'm sorry

Comment: For some reason, when i remove the params and put them into post fields, i don't get the "true" response that i was receiving with the same token. I also get the message you received.